# Electron Framework - TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

Tags: electron

I am new to Electron Framework and I am trying out an application where I need to launch a particular software (e.g. firefox) on a menu item click in my app.

Right now I am trying to build the app on Windows platform (using Windows 7).

Use case
 - Home page with static content
 - Application menu on top with 'Launch my software' as a menu item
 - On click of this menu item I want to launch a software which is installed on my system (I know the path to the exe file)

### Steps to create and start the project

1. npm init (to enter the details of the project and create package.json)
2. npm install electron --save-dev --verbose
3. created main.js and main.html (simple HTML file with a header) as mentioned below
4. npm start

### Contents of main.js as follows

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const { Menu } = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

var childProc = electron.ChildProcess;
var mainWindow;

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Menu',
        submenu: [{
            label: 'Launch my Software',
            click: function () {
                var child = childProc.exec;
                var executablePath = "<path to executable for the software>";

                child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(data.toString());
                });
            }
        }]
    }
]);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/main.html');
    mainWindow.setMenu(menu);
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow == null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

After doing npm start, the project is launched. But when I click on the menu item to launch my software, I get the following error

Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined

and it is pointing at line no. 18
                var child = childProc.exec;

I went through different posts and tried out the suggestions but it has not worked for me. Can anyone pls help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron doesn't have a `ChildProcess` method or property.

If you want to `exec` a command then use;

```
const childProcess = require('child_process')

childProcess.exec('')
```